# How can I check if a RecordZone is shared with CloudKit?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

I am interested in checking if a RecordZone has been shared. When I share a zone, I know there is a share record created in that zone. In Apple's CloudKit example, it checks to see if a specific record is shared:

```
func fetchOrCreateShare(contact: Contact) async throws -> (CKShare, CKContainer) {
   guard let existingShare = contact.associatedRecord.share else {
    let share = CKShare(rootRecord:contact.associatedRecord)      
   share[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = "Contact: \.(contact.name)" 
    _ = try await database.modifyRecords(saving:[contact.associatedRecord, share], deleting: []). 
    return (share, container)
  }
  guard let share = try await database.record(for: existingShare) as? CKShare else {
    throw ViewModelError.invalidRemoteShare
  }
  return (share, container)
}
```

The first line of the method `guard let existingShare = contact.associatedRecord.share` checks if a specific record is being shared, but in the case of a shared zone, given a zone name, how can I check the `.share` of that zone? When I try `CKRecordZone(zoneName: "Contacts").share`, the value is nil even though the zone is being shared.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is explained in the [CKShare docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare) shown in bold below:

> After CloudKit saves the share, a participant can fetch its
> corresponding metadata, which includes a reference to the share,
> information about the user’s participation, and, for shared
> hierarchies, the root record’s record ID. Create an instance of
> CKFetchShareMetadataOperation using the share’s URL and add it to the
> container’s queue to execute it. The operation returns an instance of
> CKShare.Metadata for each URL you provide. This is only applicable if
> you manually process share acceptance. If a user receives the share
> URL and taps or clicks it, CloudKit automatically processes their
> participation.
>
> To determine the configuration of a fetched share,
> inspect the recordName property of its recordID. **If the value is
> CKRecordNameZoneWideShare, the share is managing a shared record zone**;
> otherwise, it’s managing a shared record hierarchy.
>
> `let isZoneWide = (metadata.share.recordID.recordName == CKRecordNameZoneWideShare)`